# codeigniter insert into syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

this is my insert sql statement:

```
$sql = "
                LOCK TABLE notre_offre WRITE;

                SELECT 
                    @myRight := rgt FROM notre_offre
                WHERE id = " . $this->input->post('category') . ";

                UPDATE notre_offre SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
                UPDATE notre_offre SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;
                INSERT INTO notre_offre(id, naziv, lft, rgt) VALUES(null, '" . $this->input->post('title') . "', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);
                UNLOCK TABLES;
                ";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

But I got syntax error:

```
"Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM notre_offre WHERE id = 2; UPD' at line 3
```

What is here problem? This works perfectly from phpmyadmin and cmd.
"

Comment: Along with Wolfgang's comment below, I'd add that from what it looks like what you're trying to do, you really needs to make it a stored procedure, or else fetch the results of the first query and use it to construct the later queries.  Also, I think that you need to put this in a transaction instead of using manual table locking.

Comment: I know this is deprecated but I am learnig from this http://web.archive.org/web/20051023020223/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html can u pls give me example of this as stored procedure or maybe givme some link where I can learn more about it?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to put something together in an answer below, but it will take a few minutes.  By the way, that's a great article; I don't know why it's so hard to find now.

Comment: Yes, just amazing, this article is no more on official, this is a copy :) thanks u a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know Codeigniter specifically, but you probably can not send more than one SQL command in one go. Try to send the individual `LOCK`, `SELECT` etc. commands with separate `query()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to tweak this, but something along these lines should get you started with creating a stored procedure in your database instead of trying to query it every time on the fly:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertNode`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`db_user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertNode` (
    pParentCategory VARCHAR(50),
    pCategory VARCHAR(50),
    pTitle VARCHAR(50)
)
    COMMENT 'Inserts a node into a hierarchical table'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    DECLARE myRight INTEGER;

    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT `rgt` INTO myRight
      FROM `notre_offre`
      WHERE `id` = pParentCategory;

    UPDATE `notre_offre` SET `rgt` = `rgt` + 2 WHERE `rgt` > myRight;
    UPDATE `notre_offre` SET `lft` = `lft` + 2 WHERE `lft` > myRight;
    INSERT INTO `notre_offre` (`id`, `naziv`, `lft`, `rgt`)
        VALUES (pCategory, pTitle, myRight + 1, myRight + 2);

    SELECT `pCategory` AS "id", pTitle as "myRight",
        (myRight + 1) AS "lft", (myRight + 2) AS "rgt";
    COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that you only have to define this *once*, not every time you want to insert a node.  As such, you can run it from your favorite DB GUI tool such as PhpMyAdmit, MySQL Workbench, etc.  After that, to insert a node, instead of trying to insert it directly into the table, you would call it like this:

```
CALL `InsertNode`('Televisions', 'Game Consoles', 'User-defined Title');
```

Like I said, though, depending on the exact fields in your table, you might have to add parameters and tweak the procedure above to work exactly how you want it to.  Still, it should be a good start.